# rails 3.2 delete object url order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-routing

When I call the delete action on my on my index.html.erb page for images, it references the correct id's and such, but it does not order them in the url correctly.  The url should look like `http://localhost:3000/admin/albums/33/images/1`, but it displays as `http://localhost:3000/admin/albums/33/images.1`.  I know it has something to do with the .:format, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  When I put this in the delete action, `admin_album_images_path([@album, image])`, it results in `http://localhost:3000/admin/albums/33/1/images.`

**routes**

```
Admin::Application.routes.draw do
  get "albums/index"

  get "dashboard/index"

  namespace :admin do
    root :to => "dashboard#index"
    resources :dashboard
    resources :albums do
      resources :images
     end
    get "admin/album"
    end
    get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
  get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
  get "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"
    # resources :users
  resources :basic
    root :to => "basic#index"
```

**Controller**

```
class Admin::ImagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images(params[:id])
        @images = Image.all
    end
    def new
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.new
    end
    def create
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.build(params[:image])
        if @image.save
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully added image!"
            redirect_to [:admin, :albums]
        else
            render :action => 'new'
        end
    end
    def show
        @album = Album.find(params[:id])
        @image = @album.images(params[:id])
    end
    def destroy
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images(params[:id])
        @image.destroy
        redirect_to admin_albums_path
    end

end
```

**View**

```
<% @images.each do |image|%>
    <%= image.title %> </br>
    <%= image.description %> </br>
    <%= image.image_name %> </br>
    <%= button_to "Delete", admin_album_images_path(@album, image), :method => :delete, :style => "display: block; float: left;" %>
    <%= debug @image %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
admin_album_image_path(@album, image)
```

note that both are singular.  you can also change that to `[:admin, @album, image]` so you don't have to worry about the name of the route

An additional parameter will by default become the format so

```
admin_album_image_path(@album, image, :csv)
```

will be converted to

```
/admin/albums/1/images/1.csv
```

Comment: Wait I got it! You are amazing... this error has been troubling me for days now